# expectation of the maximum function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose we have $X,Y$ independent normally distributed r.v. $X \sim \mathcal N(a,\sigma^2_1)$, $Y \sim \mathcal N(a,\sigma^2_2)$, and $Z=\rho X+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}Y$ where $\rho$ is some constant.

How can I calculate the $\mathbb{E}[\max(0,e^Z-e^Y)]$?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a mistake?  If $X,Y$ are independent then their correlation $\rho$ is 0, so $Z=Y$ and this is  trivial.

Comment: I mean $\rho$ to be not the correlation, but just some constant

Comment: If you say two random variables are normally distributed and specify their means and variances, then you've said what their separate distributions are, but if you add to that their correlation, then that falls short of specifying their joint distribution.  But then if you also say they're _jointly_ normally distributed, then that fully specifies their distribution.

Comment: If $X \sim \mathcal N(a,\sigma^2_1)$, $Y \sim \mathcal N(a,\sigma^2_2)$, and $Z=\rho X+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}Y$ and $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $Z \sim \mathcal N\left(\rho a + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\  a,\ \  \rho^2\sigma_1^2 + (1-\rho^2)\sigma_2^2\right)$.

Comment: ...and you need to think about the covariance, and hence the correlation, between $Y$ and $Z$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $\mathbb E[ \max(0, \mathrm e^Z - \mathrm e^Y) ] = \mathbb E \left[ \mathrm e^Z - \mathrm e^Y | Z>Y \right] \mathrm P(Z>Y) $